# Good scripting language with int64/uint64 support which can be embedded

Tags: library, c++, scripting

Is there any scripting language which has native int64/uint64 support?
I want to use this in a C++ game, so I need these features:

- Can call it's functions from C++
- Cross-platform (Windows + Linux would be enough)
- C-like syntax
- OOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is widely used for such scripting.

It has all the features OP requested, and integrates well with C and C++ programs.

See http://www.lua.org/

Comment: Lua uses double for all numbers. Its syntax is also quite unlike C/C++. Indices are 1-based. Having said that it is light weight, easily integrated. We use it in WinGate

Comment: The latest version uses `long long` and `unsigned long long` where available. (e.g. MSVC++ 14.0) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Python? It is Object-Oriented. Integers size is dynamic, can be 64 bit signed/unsigned. Some popular games uses it - Civilization IV for sure, I think I have found some Python files in Act of War: Direct Action files as well.

Comment: Python's syntax is weird IMO.

Comment: Depends on which were your starting languages. I did start with Py.

Comment: I'm good with C-style syntax.